Proceeding of chemical reaction and stoichiometry
Suppose two reactants react to form more than one product depending upon the quantities taken. So I assumed that one of the reactant will become limiting reagent, another reactant remains unreacted,  and accordingly only one product will be formed.
However, on many sources I see that instead of that, two products are formed, with their algebra dependent on stoichiometry.
Consider this for example,
20 grams of O₂ and 12 grams of Carbon.
The two possible reactions are,
C + O₂ → CO₂
C + 1/2 O₂ → CO
Now, 20 grams O₂ means 20/32= 0.625 moles
And 12 grams C is 1 mole.
So I thought,
0.625 mole C will react with 0.625 mole O₂ , forming 0.625 mole CO₂ , and 0.375 mole C remains unreacted.
However, according to texts,
Let x mole of C react with x mole O₂
to form x mole CO₂
and (1-x) mole C react with (1-x)/2 mole O₂ to form (1-x) mole CO.
∴ Total moles of O₂,
x + (1-x)/2 = 0.625.
Solving we get, x = 0.25 moles.
This tells that none of the reactant is left unreacted, and two different products are formed.
Which one is correct and why?
( Please suggest some sources to know more about such issues if you know. Thanks. )

Depending on the conditions, either may be correct.

First, you must consider that the reaction isn't "smart"; it's probably not going to proceed in a way that perfectly uses up all the C and all the O2. The reaction doesn't "know" ahead of time how much of each reactant it has to work with, so it can't plan ahead in terms of what reaction to do. Many (most?) reactions are reversible, so a balance has to be struck between the forward reaction occurring and the reverse reaction occurring; even if there's plenty of reactants left, the forward reaction might not occur if it's not particularly favorable when compared to the reverse reaction. But it's true that combustion is (essentially) irreversible and is an exception to this.
When deciding which reaction will occur, you have to think about which one is more likely at any given time. In the example you gave, the C and O2 will probably initially react to make mostly CO2, since CO2 is more stable than CO (see https://www.quora.com/Why-does-carbon-react-with-oxygen-to-form-carbon-dioxide-instead-of-carbon-monoxide for an explanation of this). But as the amount of O2 decreases, it will be less and less likely for a collision to occur between C and O2 that makes carbon dioxide--there will simply be fewer opportunities for enough O2 to collide with C to make CO2 (sorry, I'm a little iffy on the reaction mechanisms here). Since the formation of CO requires less oxygen than the formation of CO2 does, CO will eventually be the major product being formed, since it won't require as much of the dwindling O2. (Forming CO2 in oxygen-rich environments is called complete combustion, and forming CO in oxygen-poor environments is called incomplete combustion.) Getting some numerical specifics about this would probably require a detailed understanding of the kinetics (rates) of the reactions and how they vary as the amounts of reactants change, and probably more than basic algebra; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_reaction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_equation#Parallel_or_competitive_reactions.
